# Convert UTC time to GMT bash script

Tags: bash, shell, date, data-conversion

I am trying to convert a UTC time to GMT time in my small script, but it doesn't work:

```
TimestampUTC=$(date +"%s")
echo $TimestampUTC
dates=$(date -d @$TimestampUTC)
echo $dates

## 2 hours difference between UTC and GMT
Hours2=120

TimestampGMT=$((TimestampUTC - Hours2))
echo $TimestampGMT

diff=$((TimestampUTC - TimestampGMT))
echo $diff

dateGMT=$(date -d @$TimestampGMT)
echo $dateGMT
```

The displayed result for `$dateGMT` is the same as `$dates`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The displayed result won't be same. Check the minutes displayed by `echo $dates` and `echo $dateGMT`, they would be different by 2 minutes or 120 seconds. If you have 2 hours difference between UTC and GMT then make `Hours2` equal to `2*60*60` since you need to write it in seconds and not minutes.

Comment: Oh yeah exactly, UTC is Mon Aug 17 09:18:20 AST 2015 and GMT is: Mon Aug 17 07:18:20 AST 2015, thanks man

Answer (score 3):

error in script.

Unix timestaps are given in seconds.

Hours2=120 means 120 seconds.

So your 2 timestaps are diverging by 2 minutes, not 2 hours.

This code is correct:

```
Hours2=7200
```

Also you claim having 2 hours between GMT and UTC, I'm sure you mean CET (central european time)

Note: there is nothing like a CET timestamp. It's just the normal unix timestamp displayed with a timezone offset. So independently of world location, the unix timestamp is always, worldwide, the same at the same instant.

You can replace all your code by just this

```
# get the timestamp 2 hours in the future from now
date2h=$(date -d "2 hours" +%s)
```

Which gives you the unix timestamp from the future. It is NOT the current timestamp in CET. The current CET timestamp is always the same as UTC.

How to get the time from UTC and CET? Set the environment variable TZ before the command.

```
$ TZ=UTC date
Mon Aug 17 11:44:05 UTC 2015
$ TZ=CET date
Mon Aug 17 13:44:05 CEST 2015
$ TZ=GMT date
Mon Aug 17 11:44:05 GMT 2015
```

but the timestap is always the same

```
$ TZ=UTC date +%s
1439812072
$ TZ=CET date +%s
1439812072
$ TZ=GMT date +%s
1439812072
```

Answer (score 1):

GMT and UTC do not differ by 2 hours. In fact they don't differ at all. So displaying the dates of GMT and UTC will always show exactly the same number.

Also I don't know bash but I find it hard to believe that 2 hours is represented by 120 minutes. Normally when doing math with dates milliseconds are used.

Comment: The difference between GMT and UTC is 3 hours, but since we have GMT+1, it is 2 hours

Comment: GMT = Greenwich. Which is UTC. GMT does not switch to summertime. For summertime in the UK, use TZ=WET. Currently middle european time is UTC+2, not UTC+3.

Comment: Right. GMT is UTC+0 always (neither use Daylight Savings Time) so it always matches. WET is UTC+0 or+1 depending on DST and CET is UTC+1 or +2. EET is +2 or +3 (that must be the one you want). And that's all the timezones I see in Europe on [timeanddate.com](http://www.timeanddate.com/)

Answer (score 0):

In your favourite terminal use the following sequence

```
export TZ=GMT; date
```

Answer (score 0):

```
date_format='+%d %B %Y %H:%M'

datatest="2021-11-21 12:00:00 UTC"
echo $(date -d "$datatest" "$date_format")
    
datatest="2021-11-21 12:00:00 CET"
echo $(date -d "$datatest" "$date_format")
   
datatest="2021-11-21 12:00:00 GMT"
echo $(date -d "$datatest" "$date_format")
```

Out:

```
21 November 2021 13:00
21 November 2021 12:00
21 November 2021 13:00
```